# Why does key = model_instance.key have No!!! next to it in the db to ndb docs?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

Previously I was using db instead of ndb. Now I'm migrating my code. The db.model equivalent of

> key = model_instance.key()

ndb.model:

> key= model_instance.key

which has a No !!! next to it. But it doesn't say what we should use instead.

How would I write in ndb? And why is this not good?

```
p.key().id()
```

Comment: Does `p.key.id()` not work?

Comment: p.key.id() should work

Comment: It does but in the docs it says No!!!! next to key = model_instance.key so I was wondering if there is something else I should use.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I presume you're referring to the [NDB Cheat Sheet](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1AefylbadN456_Z7BZOpZEXDq8cR8LYu7QgI7bt5V0Iw/mobilebasic), more specifically to the 4th row in the **Entities** table:

> ```
> key = model_instance.key()  |   key = model_instance.key  # no () !!
> ```

The text is actually `# no () !!`, meaning no parenthesis/not a function call. Which is correct in the context as that's the method of obtaining the entity's key, which is an attribute in `ndb`, vs. a function call in `db`. It doesn't mean "do not use".

Comment: well... this explains it

Comment: I was referring to https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/db_to_ndb which looks to be very similar to the document you referenced. Ah that clears up what it means. Thanks.